# cli::array<Byte> as member in mixed class

Tags: c++-cli, mixed-mode, pin-ptr

I want to have a managed buffer as a member in mixed class:

```
class A {
    cli::array<Byte> m_managedBuffer;
}
```

This results in:

> error C3265: cannot declare a managed 'm_managedBuffer' in an unmanaged 'A'

So I tried using auto_gcroot:

```
class A {
    auto_gcroot<cli::array<Byte> ^> m_managedBuffer;
}
```

And got the following error:

> error C2106: '=' : left operand must be l-value

My solution is to use a managed wrapper

```
ref class ByteArray
{
    public:
    ByteArray(size_t size) {
          m_bytes = gcnew cli::array<Byte>(size);
    }

    cli::array<Byte> ^ m_bytes;
};
```

I don't like this because it introduces a level of indirection to get to the actual buffer and furthermore, when I want to pin the managed buffer (pin_ptr) - how do I do it? Can I just pin the inner m_bytes memeber without pinning the outer ByteArray object?

> **Solution**: Use gcroot instead of auto_gcroot. The managed byte array
>   will be cleaned up by GC, doesn't have to be under auto_gcroot.

Comment: Have you tried using a regular gcroot instead of auto_gcroot?

Comment: gcroot does indeed work. From what I understand, the difference between auto_gcroot and gcroot is that auto_gcroot automatically releases the memory used. Should I be worried that my managed buffers aren't cleaned up by the GC?

Comment: From what I've read, the difference is that auto_gcroot calls `IDisposable::Dispose()`. A simple byte array should be GC'd correctly after the regular gcroot no longer references it.